# Will creating a thread for every user of my API scale well?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, api-design

I am building an API that will interact with the Spotify API in Java Spark. I went with the Authorization Code Flow for the token management - which means that the token will be valid for an hour (for a given user), and then needs to refresh.

For every user that connects their Spotify account, I create a Timer that will check if the user was active after 50 minutes:

If yes -> I refresh the user's token.
If no -> I delete the user together with the user's token, which means that they will have to login again if they want to use my service (for storage purposes).

I also keep a HashMap with a User-object, with various information from every user like their profile names, images, playlists etc. This is also deleted from the HashMap if the check from the timer proves that this user was inactive.

**The PROBLEM:**
Every Timer-object creates a new Thread. If there was, theoretically, thousands of users using my service, there would be thousands of threads... My intuition tells me that this is unacceptable. I can not seem to wrap my head around this. How should I go about to keep track of when 50 minutes has passed for every user, while maintaining as few threads as possible and not "over-powering" the API? Any tips would be appreciated!

Code:

```
package Authentication;

import Spotify.Users.UserSessions;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class RefreshTokens extends TimerTask {
    private UserSessions userSessions;
    private Authentication authentication;
    private String currentUserSession;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(true);

    public RefreshTokens(UserSessions userSessions, Authentication authentication, String currentUserSession) {
        this.userSessions = userSessions;
        this.authentication = authentication;
        this.currentUserSession = currentUserSession;
    }

    public void startAutomaticProcess() {
        timer.schedule(this, 20000, 20000); //runs every 20 seconds for testing purposes
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Automatic process started: " + new Date());
        refresh();
    }

    private void refresh() {
        if (userSessions.contains(currentUserSession)) {
            if (userSessions.get(currentUserSession).isActive()) {
                authentication.refreshToken(userSessions.get(currentUserSession));
            } else {
                System.out.println("User was not active enough and has been removed from the server.");
                System.out.println("----------");
                System.out.println("Size of HashMap before: " + userSessions.getHashMap().size());
                userSessions.getHashMap().remove(currentUserSession);
                System.out.println("Size of HashMap after: " + userSessions.getHashMap().size());
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a new instance of this class for every new user and call the startAutomaticProcess() method.

Comment: Thread pools. Also you might want to look into fibers.

Comment: @m0skit0 Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I have thought about Thread pools - but wouldn't that bring some limitations as well? As every Timer object needs a Thread, having a pool, of lets say 20 threads, wouldn't these Threads all be busy for the first 20 users? I am going to read about Thread Pools now, maybe I will find an answer.

Comment: "This class is preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor (which this class extends) are required"
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Or flip this around: have one process check all "userSessions" every minute or so to see which users need a token-refresh and fire a task (into a threadpool) to do the refresh when needed.

Comment: I might be wrong on that one, but why do you even want to do this? You refresh the token, when it's needed. Meaning: User or your program requests something, you have the expiry date for the token, if it's expired, you acquire a new one. But you don't refresh those tokens greedily. That's not how it's supposed to work. I would (personally) overthink this whole algorithm, if it's needed or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I appreciate it! 
@maio290 Indeed, I did change the system. If I wouldn't have a very tight time schedule I would have went with an implementation in the style of what Stephen C wrote. I ended up just authenticating the user for every call, while keeping an active label of every user. If a user is not active, he will be thrown out after 45 minutes for storage purposes, and will have to re-authenticate. This scales much better as I only need one thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will creating a thread for every user of my API scale well?

Clearly no.

Each thread has a thread stack which uses *at least* 64K bytes and by default 1MB;  see:

- [My application has a lot of threads and is running out of memory, why?](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom)

So, if the number of users increases you will run out of memory.  This is not scalable.

Furthermore, each thread needs to wake up each time that a refresh is performed.  That entails 2 context switches and associated overheads.

Suggestion:

- Create a `UserToken` class that represents each user token, and includes a timestamp for when the token was last checked.
- Create `PriorityQueue<UserToken>` that is ordered on the tokens' timestamps.
- Use a `TimerTask` to remove `UserToken` objects from the priority queue that need checking.
- When the check succeeds (i.e. the user is still active), update the timestamp and re-add the `UserToken` to the queue.

This approach requires scales much better.  Assume that `N` is the number of authenticated users:

- There is just one thread rather than `N` threads and `TimerTask` objects.
- The thread needs to wake up once every `M` minutes, rather than `N` threads all waking up once every `M2` minutes.
- It needs less than 500 bytes<sup>1</sup> per active user rather than 64K (minimum).
- Priority queue insertion/re-insertion is cheap, and scales as `O(logN)`.

---

<sup>1 - The space consists of the `UserToken` object and its subsidiary objects, and the internal "node" in the priority queue.  100 to 200 bytes is a better estimate, though this will be implementation specific.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this excellent and clear description! First time working on an API - this helped me out with the structure. Cheers.